# Is Backward-Euler method considered the same as Runge Kutta $2^{\text{nd}}$ order method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods, eulers-method

I have a book that quotes:

> Euler's method, ***Modified Euler's method*** and Runge's method are
>   Runge-Kutta methods of first, ***second*** and third order respectively. The
>   fourth-order Runge-Kutta method is method is most commonly used and is
>   often referred to as 'Runge-Kutta method' or 'classical Runge-Kutta
>   method'

Similary Wikipedia categorizes Backward-Euler's method as ' Implicit methods' under the [list of Runge-Kutta methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods) and also mentions:

> The backward Euler method is **first** order.

Now the problem is that the same book (from which I have taken the above quote) solves the below problem using a method that seems *quite different*(at least to me) from the Backward-Euler's method.

> Consider the first order initial value problem
>   $y'=y+2x-x^{2}$,$y(0)=1$,$(0\le x\le\infty)$ with exact solution
>   $y(x)=x^2+e^x$. For $x=0.1$, what is solution obtained using a single
>   iteration of the **second-order Runge-Kutta** method with step size
>   $h=0.1$

The book then shows the solution using:

> $$k_1=hf(x_0,y_0)$$ $$k_2=hf(x_0+h,y_0+k_1)$$
>   $$y_1=y_0+\frac{1}{2}(k_1+k_2)$$

Here $f$ denotes the differential equation i.e. $y'=f(x,y)=y+2x-x^{2}$. Using the above equations and initial value, it gets the result as $y_1=1.1145$.

I tried to calculate the vaule using Backward-Euler's method using:

$$y_{1}=y_{0}+hf(x_{1},y_{1})$$
and I get the result as $y_1=1.1322$, which is different from the solution given in the book.

---

So I have the following questions:

1. Is Backward-Euler method considered the **same** as Runge-Kutta
   $2^{\text{nd}}$ order (RK2) method? If yes, is my book incorrect with
   the solution?
2. Is the method used in the book the actual Runge-Kutta
       $2^{\text{nd}}$ order method which is completely **different** from Backward-Euler's method?
3. In case my first question's answer is **yes**, how can a method be a Runge-Kutta $2^{\text{nd}}$ order (RK2) while also
   being a  $1^{\text{st}}$ order in itself? (no need to answer if first question's answer is **no**)

I am really confused with the way the book used the name Backward Euler as RK2 but then used a different method to solve a question that wanted RK2. Please help me understand this.

**Note**: My book states Backward Euler as Modified Euler's method (In case it's not so obvious).

Comment: How did you find the $y_1$ to put into $f$?  Whether they are the same or not depends on this initial calculation.

Comment: @Paul are you talking about the Euler's method ?

Comment: yes, the implicit Euler one.

Comment: @Paul if you use $y_1=y_0+h(y_1+2x_1-x_{1}^2)$ then you should be able to find $y_1$ as $h,x_1,y_0$ are all provided.

Comment: Your are then using forward Euler's to evaluate $y_1$ to put into $f$, but that is not the only way of determining the $y_1$ to put into $f$.

Comment: @Paul I am sorry but I don't quite understand what you are trying to say here, that's the formula for [Backward-Euler's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_Euler_method). Adding to this, I am not using forward Euler's to evaluate $y_1$

Comment: Backward's Euler is given by $y_{1}=y_{0}+hf(x_{1},y_{1})$, but that tells you nothing about how to find a $y_1$ to insert into $f$.  Any explicit method works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82882/discussion-between-paulplusx-and-paul).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the first order implicit backwards Euler method is different from the second order explicit trapezoidal or Heun method.

In your question you name and describe both methods correctly.

The list in the first book quote only refers to explicit methods, at no point is there a reference to the implicit backward Euler method.

---

To recap:

- Forwards Euler method: $$y_{k+1}=y_k+h\,f(x_k,y_k)$$
- Backwards Euler method: $$y_{k+1}=y_k+h\,f(x_{k+1},y_{k+1}),$$ which in general requires the solution of a non-linear equation.
- Implicit trapezoidal method: $$\frac{y_{k+1}-y_k}h=\frac{f(x_k,y_k)+f(x_{k+1},y_{k+1})}2,$$ which again requires the solution of an in general non-linear equation. It is noted for its time symmetry.
- Explicit trapezoidal method, modified Euler method, Heun's method: $$\frac{y_{k+1}-y_k}h=\frac{f(x_k,y_k)+f(x_{k+1},\tilde y_{k+1})}2,~~\text{ where }~~\tilde y_{k+1}=y_k+h\,f(x_k,y_k)$$ is a sufficiently accurate approximation of the implicit method. In the form of stages based on a Butcher tableau it is \begin{align}k_1&=h\,f(x_k,y_k),\\k_2&=h\,f(x_k+h,y_k+k_1),\\y_{k+1}&=y_k+\frac12(k_1+k_2).\end{align}

Comment: But the book quotes as you see in the first paragraph `Modified Euler's method` and like I have written in my note it `states Backward Euler as Modified Euler's method`, I meant the implicit one. So is it safe to assume that the first quote(from my book) is wrong and the implicit Backward-Euler is not RK2 ? The list is from Wikipedia not from my book.

Comment: Where do you see that? The second quote names the second order Runge-Kutta method a.k.a. Heun method and the third quote gives the details of exactly that method.

Comment: I am talking about the very first quote `Euler's method, Modified Euler's method and Runge's method are Runge-Kutta methods of first, second and third order respectively.`

Comment: All one-step methods with a Butcher tableau are Runge-Kutta methods. There are two commonly used second order RK methods, the midpoint method and the trapezium method. Also known in their explicit variants as improved and modified Euler methods. I assume that Runge's method is the shortened RK4 method. There is nothing wrong in your book quotes.

Comment: So ultimately you mean to say that there are two RK2 one is **Implicit Backward-Euler** and other one is **Heun's method**?

Comment: No, implicit backward Euler is one of the RK1 methods.

Comment: I am getting a bit confused so I'll try to clear things up. My book explains Modified Euler as implicit Backward Euler and the same book states that Modified Euler is RK2, so isn't my book wrong?

Comment: Could you give the source for "My book explains Modified Euler as implicit Backward Euler" as that is neither in the quotes nor in the image in the chat.

Comment: Please see the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82882/discussion-between-paulplusx-and-paul) now

Comment: Ok, so it is the title of that (sub-)section that has you stumped. And I agree, it is a bit disingenuous. However it makes sense to discuss the first order Euler methods before introducing improved or modified variants. Note that the methods used are properly named and nowhere is it claimed that they are second order or the announced modified Euler method. You should find that on the next pages.

Comment: I have uploaded a second image (the next page of my book) as well in the chat that quotes that Modified Euler is RK2. Please have a look.

Comment: I saw your edited answer now. It now perfectly clear to me. The only thing that is wrong in my book is that they have mentioned the heading (or sub) as **Modified Euler** and have shown **Implicit Backward Euler** but now seeing your answers I can understand that both of them are different. Thank you so much for bearing with me and clearing my confusion. I wish I could vote more than once for your diligent effort :)